# How to compile packages in java?

Tags: java

I have written a simple package program:

---

```
  //A simple package

       package MyPack


       class Balance
       {
        String name;
        double bal;

        Balance(String n, double b)
        {
            name=n;
                    bal=b;
            }

        void show()
            {
            if(bal<0)
            System.out.println("-->");
            System.out.println(name+ ": $:" +bal);
        }
        }

        class AccountBalance
        {
            public static void main(String args[])
            {
                       Balance current[]=new Balance[3];
                    current[0]=new Balance("A.K.Juwatkar",123.123);
                    current[1]=new Balance("A.P.Dhoke",345.67);
                    current[2]=new Balance("Anil Sarang",100.98);

                    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                current[i].show();
               }
        }
```

---

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 &
When i compile it using

```
java MyPack.AccountBalance
```

I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MyPack/AccountBalance
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyPack.AccountBalance
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: MyPack.AccountBalance. Program will exit.
```

What is wrong? Please help me out.
I have installed openjdk, do i need to install anything else??
I am using Ubuntu 10.04, kindly help me out

Comment: Have you imported mypack.Balance in Account balance?

Comment: http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/compile-and-run-java-program-in-package-from-command-line/

Comment: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J9c_PackageClasspath.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Best is to compile and run the classes from outside the packages :

First you compile with javac :

```
$javac MyPack/AccountBalance.java
```

this will create a new file in the MyPack folder called AccountBalance.class

then you can run it :

```
$java MyPack.AccountBalance
```

By the way: it is discouraged to have package names start with a capital.

Answer (score 18):

When you are trying to compile the java class, use the '-d' option (destination) to specify where the .class files should be located.

```
javac -d "classes" AccountBalance.java
```

and when you run your program, make sure that same folder is included in your class path:

```
java -classpath "classes" MyPack.AccountBalance
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to create the folder named `MyPack` and move .class files in it or use following command line to compile the java code and it moves the .class files into `MyPack` folder.

```
javac YourFileName.java -d .
```

and run using,

```
java MyPack.AccountBalance
```

Have a look at  [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html) tool

> From the tool doc : By default, the compiler puts each class file in the same directory as
>   its source file. You can specify a separate destination directory with
>   -d (see Options, below).

and [package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) tutorial.

Comment: I compiled by
javac AccountBalance.java

got no errors there
But when i tried to run using

java MyPack.AccountBalance
i got the following msg:

Comment: @user1388626 You need to create MyPack folder and move Balance.class and AccountBalance.class in it. Or use -d switch so the javac tool creates the package folder.

Comment: I have placed AccountBalance.java file in MyPack folder

Comment: @user1388626 then come out from this folder (back to parent of MyPack) and run the >java MyPack.AccountBalance

Answer (score 3):

If you're frequently compiling and running via `javac` and `java` commands then use

```
javac MyJavaClass.java && java MyJavaClass
```

This'll compile the the class then run the class you just compiled.

Note: Replace `&&` with `;` if using Windows powershell.

Comment: with `java` command you don't need to specify the `.class` extension, but only the fully-qualified class name of the class containing the `main` method

Comment: Windows uses this syntax too.

Comment: @Nahiyan Windows cmd uses this syntax, but Windows powershell uses `;` to run one command after another. Updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand java command. If you want to compile a java code like MyClass.java .

```
package myPackage
public class MyClass{
  ...
}
```

compile the package

```
javac -d . MyClass.java
```

which will create /myPackage/MyClass.class in "."(current directory).

-d means destination directory.

Then run it.

```
java myPackage.MyClass
```