# How to compile and run a java class with a package

Tags: java, package, javac

I have a class called MyClass in the file MyClass.java file (code mentioned below)

```
package myclass;

class MyClass {
  public int add (int a, int b){
    return a+b;   
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    System.out.println(oobj.add(2, 3));
  }
}
```

I am compiling the class with

```
javac MyClass.java
```

But I am trying to run the class using

```
java MyClass
```

or

```
java myclass.MyClass
```

I am getting the Error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass
```

But, I am able to run this program if I omit out the package name.
where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your class should be `public`

Comment: This class doesnt seem as if it compiles to begin with. Post your real code

Comment: relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546720/how-to-compile-packages-in-java

Comment: I have changed MyClass to public, but but running java MyClass -or- java myclass.MyClass throws error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that you are inside the parent directory of the package folder (the folder in which your compiled class file is), and execute the following command:

```
java myclass.MyClass
```

Below is an example file structure:

```
bin
    -> myclass
        -> MyClass.class
```

In the example structure above, you would have to execute the command from the "bin" directory.

Also, define the class as `public` and recompile the java source file.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this too. It's very frustrating for someone from other languages.  The key here is, the java file has to be in the right directory depending on the package declaration.

if the java file Test1.java starts with

```
package com.xyz.tests;
```

Then the java file Test1.java needs to be in directory `com/xyz/tests`

You can compile and run as

```
javac com/xyz/tests/Test1.java
java com/xyz/tests/Test1
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Compile The Class using :

```
javac -d ./myclass
```

Comment: Sorry That Was Wrong . The Right One is :

Comment: javac -d . Myclass.java

Answer (score 0):

I get my example to run by

```
java <package>.<class>
```

From parent directory of package