# I am not able to run my javaProgram in Terminal Mac os

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I used Netbeans to write program but want to run in terminal to check wether socket programming is working or not. I was able to compile the first file ServerClient.java successfully but not able to run. here is my programming files

ServerProgram.java

```
package echoserver;

public class ServerProgram {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java Server <port number>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    try (
        ServerSocket serverSocket =
            new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);                   
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    ) {
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(inputLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
            + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

ClientProgram.java

```
package echoserver;

public class ClientProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.err.println(
            "Usage: java Client <host name> <port number>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String hostName = args[0];
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    try (
        Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out =
            new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in))
    ){
        String userInput;
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("socket: " + in.readLine());
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
            hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } 
}
```

}

cmd:

```
Puja:echoserver pujadudhat$ javac ServerProgram.java
Puja:echoserver pujadudhat$ $javac ServerProgram.java -d
-bash: ServerProgram.java: command not found
Puja:echoserver pujadudhat$
```

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Answer (score 0):

Compile the code as follow:

```
$javac YourJavaFileName.java -d .
```

In your case:  `$javac ServerProgram.java -d .`.

Then run as follow:

```
$java PackageName.ClassName
```

In your case: `java echoserver.ServerProgram`.

You can refer another similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546720/how-to-compile-packages-in-java).

Comment: Puja:echoserver pujadudhat$                                                                     $javac ServerProgram.java -d
   -bash: ServerProgram.java: command not found
Puja:echoserver pujadudhat$

Comment: Remove the `$` from command. In terminal type `javac ServerProgram.java -d .`  .